# Add UIScrollView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am trying to add a UIScrollView to an existing UIViewController (with navigation and tab bar) using storyboard and autolayout but I don't get this to work. Up to now I have added all components to the controller by dragging them on it. Now I try to group them in a UIView, so that I can make this UIView a subview of UIScrollView. When I drag my existing components as a subview of my newly created UIView the position of it is wrong. So I must manually correct all positions. Afterwards the compoents are 64px below their old position.

I just cant get it to work. Is there a tutorial or something how to add an UIScrollView to an existing storyboard?

Comment: Why don't you want to add it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to learn how to control a UIScrollViewer within a Storyboard.

http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uiscrollview-examples/

Comment: Embbed in -> Scroll View. Looks easy. But before I must add all components to one UIView. Can I tell XCode to not change the position of a component when it gets added to a UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to deselect Ajust Scroll View Insets in interface builder.

[image]

You can also set in your viewDidLoad :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```